# $event with $scope in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am showing a div  using `$event` with `$scope` element

here is my code

```
 <a href="#" class="pen" data-ng-click="updatePen($event,$index)"></a>


$scope.updatePen=function($event,$index){
    $event.$scope.hideField=true;
}
```

This is not working and throwing me error:

> $event.$scope is undefiend.

I want to show  a particular `div` which is clicked 
Is there is any way to do this

Answer (score 0):

No such thing as `$event.$scope` in AngularJS. I'm guessing you need this:

```
<div ng-repeat="pen in pens"> 
    <a href="#" class="pen" data-ng-click="updatePen(pen)"></a>
    <span ng-class="{'hidden': pen.hidden}">some hidden stuff here</span>
</div>

$scope.pens = [{id: 1, hidden: true}, {id: 2, hidden: true}];
$scope.updatePen = function(pen){
    pen.hidden = false;
}

.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: i m using ng-repeat .. it will hide all